# Is Google input tool available to use in website input translation or not?

Tags: transliteration, google-input-tools

i'm trying to use this: https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started , when i'm use this it shows following error:
Loading "elements" other than "inputtools" is unsupported.
and in its top gives following message:

*The Google Transliterate API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy.*

any one help me how can i use this?

Comment: same problem but but google deprecated this. Anyone who know about other tools like  this?